# Is 'I'm not in love with you' a performative action?

Tags: language, love

Is 'I'm not in love with you' a performative action?

> These statements, just by speaking them, carry out a certain action
> and exhibit a certain level of power

I seem to have a huge problem getting people to say it, and much to my chagrin (so I'm serially ghosted instead). Not asking what that means about me, or indeed my ghosts, though I suspect it's a gender and sexuality thing. I am asking whether in lieu of them saying it they haven't stoped doing so, being in love, however they express that and with whatever toxicity.

If so, can we perform that same action with e.g. silence and general mistreatment?

Comment: Is it an action?

Comment: "I seem to have a huge problem getting people to say it. . . " Do you mean saying "I'm in love with you" or saying "I'm not in love with you"?

Comment: I can understand anyone who prefers to walk away in silence rather than taking it out, if talking means becoming trapped in endless meaningless discussions.

Comment: how can I be at -5 for this, like this is the worst question and answer the site has ever seen. baffling

Answer (score 1):

It would be better if you worded the question: Can the *utterance* of "I'm not in love with you" be a performative action? We need to be clear about the type/token distinction when thinking about sentences and utterances.

Once that distinction is clear, the answer is yes, it can be, if uttered in the right circumstance, i.e. when uttered by an appropriate person, to the appropriate audience, under appropriate circumstances, etc. The fact that "I'm not in love with you" is a proposition with a truth value does not preclude its utterance from being a performative.

The whole theory of performatives was introduced by John Austin in his book, How to Do Things with Words. In his examples, he mostly uses utterances that are not truth-evaluable, but he does not exclude them. One of his examples is a sign saying, "This bull is dangerous", which is both a statement with a truth value and an act of warning. He describes utterances such as, "I'm sorry for what I did" as half-descriptive, since it is both truth-evaluable and a performative act of apologising when said sincerely under the right circumstances.

Going beyond Austin's account of performatives to John Searle's, Searle allows that assertions (and denials) are also capable of being performatives, so the utterance, "I'm not in love with you" could count as a performative declaration under the appropriate circumstances.

---

As a light-hearted aside, the opposite, "I love you", when said by a man to a woman can be a performative with any of the following meanings:

- I'm sorry for whatever it was I did.
- I forgot to buy you a birthday present; this will have to do.
- Huh? I wasn't listening.
- What did I forget? Give me some time to think.
- Please sleep with me.
- Stop nagging me.

Comment: probably would've been nicer as a comment to my answer, but thanks

Comment: @Anon The purpose of this site is to allow for a pluralism of responses. In this case, this answer contains explicit mention of Austin and Searle and their differences, mentions the type-token distinction, invokes the utterance to suggest medium-message dichotomy, and makes explicit the name of the theory in question. While I would have sprinkled a response with reference to later Wiitgenstein and language-games, the use of humor is commendable and certainly runs true as an illustration, and as such, is written more clearly.

Comment: Hence, this answer certainly shouldn't be relegated to a mere coment. It's more informative. ; )

Comment: I voted down cos it involved too much bumpf for me. YYMV. as a wild guess, I imagine that searle's and Austin's famous commentaries do not mention types or tokens, so this is original research -1

Comment: yeah I was correct, not one hit for "type" "token" in "how to do things with words" aren't i an asshole @JD

Comment: @anon Well, you are certainly entitled to your vote and your opinion. The question is, is it informed, and that's an empirical question. But before I lay bare your "expertise", I want you to understand the system: your downvote removes a couple of points, but my upvote adds ten points. Thus, a contributor is 8 points ahead anytime we disagree in such a fashion. Now, let's respond to your comment about "original research"...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131845/discussion-between-j-d-and-anon).